# Is there a way to use heatmap.js in nextjs app as a component?

Tags: javascript, heatmap

As i cannot use that as a component, i have to set the component in the hard mode

```js
var heatmapInstance = h337.create({
   // only container is required, the rest will be defaults
   container: document.getElementById('heatmap')
});
```

but i wanted a way to have something more like that:

```js
<Heatmap data:{}></Heatmap>
```